# unable to get response from google recaptcha

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, curl, recaptcha

I am working in an application by using codeigniter framework back end as mysql. In  login page I am trying  to apply Google recaptcha as given by [recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).

For this i have added curl.php library in application/library given by [codeigniter-curl](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl/tree/master/libraries)

and in my controller I am writing following code

```
$recaptchaResponse = trim($this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response'));
$userIp=$this->input->ip_address();
$secret='MY_KEY';
$url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response;=".$recaptchaResponse."&remoteip;=".$userIp;
$response = $this->curl->simple_get($url);
$status= json_decode($response, true);
if($status['success']){    
   $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Google Recaptcha Successful');
  }else{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Sorry Google Recaptcha Unsuccessful!!');
  }
```

in controller I am adding following libraries

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$this->load->library('javascript');
$this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
```

But unable to get response from

```
$this->curl->simple_get($url);
```

I am not getting what I am missing in my code. please guide me for above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl errors to gather more information about the root cause of the error.

```
if(curl_errno($c))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}
```